# How to know the name of the thread inside it

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have created multiple threads using for loop and I need to read the name of the thread inside the thread. How do I do that? I used threading.Thread.name but returns some memory address of the thread object. here is part of my code:

```
def catch_sharp_fall(update, context, x):
    global access_token, watchlist, bot, chat_id, market_open_alert, nifty, bot_reset, stop_catch_sharp_fall, \
        kite_api_key
    ins_code = x
    kite = KiteConnect(kite_api_key)
    kite.set_access_token(access_token)
    kws = KiteTicker(kite_api_key, access_token)

    def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
        logging.debug("Ticks: {}".format(ticks))

    def on_connect(ws, response):
        ws.subscribe([ins_code])
        ws.set_mode(ws.MODE_FULL, [ins_code])

    def on_close(ws, code, reason):
        ws.stop()

    kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
    kws.on_connect = on_connect
    kws.on_close = on_close
    kws.connect(threaded=True)

    while True:
        def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
            feed_data(ticks)

        def feed_data(ticks):
            list_of_threads_running = [i.name for i in threading.enumerate()]
            logging.info(f'list of threads running {list_of_threads_running}')
            # update.message.reply_text(f'<b>I am the stock {ins_code}</b>', parse_mode='HTML')
            logging.info(f'{threading.Thread.name}')

        kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
for x in watchlist:
    t = threading.Thread(name=str(x), target=catch_sharp_fall, args=(update, context, x))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Threads don't really have a name. They generally have Thread-0 and Thread-1. I recommend looking into thread pools in your situation

Comment: `threading.current_thread().name`

Answer (score 3):

When you do `threading.Thread.name`, you're retrieving `name` on the `Thread` type itself, not on the thread object for the current thread. You need to look it up on the current thread object:

```
threading.current_thread().name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`threading.current_thread().name`**, **`t1.name`** and **`t2.name`** as shown below:

```py
import threading

def test1():                             
    print(threading.current_thread().name) # "Thread-1"

def test2():
    print(threading.current_thread().name) # "test_thread"
                                                              
t1 = threading.Thread(target=test1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=test2, name="test_thread")
                                    # Thread name
t1.start()
t2.start()                         
t1.join()
t2.join()
print(t1.name) # "Thread-1"
print(t2.name) # "test_thread"
print(threading.current_thread().name) # "MainThread"
```